# add a css class to an object inside a list

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how I could add a class to a specific object inside a list?

Let me demonstrate the question with some code.

```js
$('.box')[5].addClass('center')
```

```css
.center{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            c-1
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-2
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-3
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-4
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-5
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-6
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-7
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-8
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            c-9
        </div>
    </div>
```

This does not work because I get an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[5].addClass is not a function`

I only want to add the class to the fifth element of the list. What can I do?

Comment: To target the DOM of selected Element you have to wirie `$($('.box')[5]).addClass('center')`   http://jsfiddle.net/fjz56wgg/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.box')` is an object not an array. So you can not use `index` like that.

You can simply use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector which selects the element at the specified index within the matched set:

```js
$('.box:eq(5)').addClass('center');
```

```css
.center{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      c-1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      c-2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      c-3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      c-4
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      c-5
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      c-6
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      c-7
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      c-8
  </div>
  <div class="box">
      c-9
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the `each` loop? Why not just select the single element by index?

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery there is something called the [eq selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

> Select the element at index n within the matched set.

Here is how to use it in your instance (remember counting starts at 0)

```js
$('.box:eq( 5 )').addClass('center')
```

```css
.center {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    c-1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-4
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-5
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-6
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-7
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-8
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-9
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you find this helpful.